# How to decode HEX code to regular text in Apple Script

Tags: perl, text, applescript, decode, encode

I'm using the todo list app *Things* from *Cultured Code* on my Mac and when I copy a link to a task to clipboard it ends up encoded as HEX code in the clipboard. No problem when I paste it into a text file – it then shows as decoded text.

But, I need to use the clipboard content in an AppleScript and have difficulties decoding it to plain text there.

I have tried multiple subroutines but they did not work in my case. Most examples that I found online deal with simple encoded URLs. And the code that I have so far works to decode for example "0348" correctly to the number 1000 but my script **cannot** decode the encoded Things link (that long line of numbers at the top).

Can somebody help me please?

Here's what I have so far:

```
-- The link to a task in THINGS, encoded: 7468696e67733a2f2f2f73686f773f69643d41463645303746462d394230462d343539332d423143332d313846303337434237363836
-- Above link to the task in THINGS, unencoded: things:///show?id=AF6E07FF-9B0F-4593-B1C3-18F037CB7686
-- Online converter: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/
-- Number 1000 encoded: 03E8

set theEncodedText to "03E8"
set theDecodedText to (do shell script "perl -e 'printf(hex(\"" & theEncodedText & "\"))'") as string

set theDisplayedText to theDecodedText
display dialog theDisplayedText
```

Thank you,
Martin

Comment: Don't ever generate code like that. Pass arguments to a program as arguments, using env vars or some other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is a *proof of concept* of how I'd handle setting to a *variable* a Things URL *link* that's saved to the clipboard as `«data url ...»` where `...` is Hex Data.

This *script* writes the `«data url ...»` to a temporary file, reads the temporary file, which is now a text string of the `«data url ...»`, and sets it as a the *value* of a *variable*, and then deletes the temporary file. It then displays the Things URL *link* as a text string or displays a message that the clipboard did not contain a 'things:///show?id=' URL link.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
if ((clipboard info) as string) contains "URL" then

    set thingsURL to "/tmp/thingsURL.tmp"

    try
        set f to open for access thingsURL with write permission
        set eof f to 0
        write (the clipboard) to f
        close access f
    on error
        close access f
    end try

    set thingsURLtext to (read thingsURL)
    tell application "System Events" to delete file thingsURL

    display dialog thingsURLtext buttons {"OK"} default button 1

else

    display dialog "The clipboard did not contain a 'things:///show?id=' URL link." buttons {"OK"} default button 1

end if
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any other *error handling* then what's shown and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial! – On a side note I heard back from the developer of the Things app and they said that they will let the "Copy link" command copy the link as plain text in the next update of Things v3.5, as opposed to putting HEX code into the clipboard as it is now.

Comment: @iLoveCode I tried out this answer to the problem you posted and it worked, so it's at least given you an interim solution to use until the *Things* update comes out.  I can't speak for you, but it does appear that user3439894 has successfully answered your question and that there are no other competing responses.  I also can't speak for user3439894, but I think selecting his/her answer would be a nice form of thanks, plus it would also help other users with a similar problem by directing them here to find a workable solution.  Good news on the *Things* update, though.